# What is a Nyquist edge?

Tags: terminology, frequency, signal-processing

I've come to this sentence and I don't understand the term *Nyquist edge*.

> Because observing in the FM band is not feasible, a sampling frequency of 200 MHz has been chosen for most of the receiver modes. This sampling results in a Nyquist edge almost at the center of the FM band.

Comment: Google? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_filter

Comment: Yes, i have found this, but didn't find it very helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In signal processing, the [Nyquist–Shannon sampling theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem) says you need at least 2 samples of a frequency to be able to perfectly reconstruct it.  So in your question, a sampling rate of $200\: \mathrm{MHz}$ means you can perfectly reconstruct frequencies in the range of $0 - 100\: \mathrm{MHz}$.  So what happens when frequencies above $100\: \mathrm{MHz}$ are present?  They fold over (are aliased) into the the $0 - 100\: \mathrm{MHz}$ range and the fold-over point at $100\: \mathrm{MHz}$ is the *Nyquist Edge*.

For example:
[image: nyqust zones about edges]
There is a pretty good article about this behavior at [here](http://electronicdesign.com/displays/what-s-inside-your-rf-signal-analyzer).

Comment: Also, for the curious, there is an **absolutely fantastic** video about frequencies, sampling rates, reconstructing signals from samples, etc. over at Xiph.org here: [http://www.xiph.org/video/vid2.shtml](http://www.xiph.org/video/vid2.shtml)