# What does a constant signal sound like?

Tags: acoustics, frequency, signal-processing

Say I was sampling a sound incorrectly and it produced a constant signal as below:

[image]

What would this signal sound like? In Matlab, it plays nothing. Is this correct?

Comment: Probably. It's aliased.

Comment: Great answer man thanks!!! I wasn't aware that all aliased signals were heard as nothing when played!!!!

Comment: No, not all aliased signals are heard as nothing, but ones in which they alias down to DC frequency will. Admittedly I neglected to mention that, but that's because I thought it was obvious.

Comment: That's why to perfectly reconstruct a signal you have to sample at at least twice the frequency.  See this question for related information: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90433/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matlab's silent output is correct. Physically, sound is a fluctuation of the molecules in some medium. If your waveform is perfectly constant, it corresponds to constant pressure: no fluctuations, meaning no sound. If it's very nearly constant, you will probably still be unable to hear the corresponding pressure wave without the aid of significant amplification.

Edit: In response to the quick comments above, an aliased signal is not *generally* silent, only in the extreme case when the wave is sampled at the same level each time. More typical undersampling will just result in a different sinusoid with possibly different amplitudes or frequencies than your original, thus the name "aliasing": the sampling process gave some new "name" to the original wave.

Comment: First good answer I've had on this exchange for ages. Thanks mate. I was being sarcastic in my above. He's very ignorant.

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly this isn't really physics-related, but I found something amusing in Mathematica when trying this:

```
Play[Sin[8000 2 Pi t], {t, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

Mathematica by default samples `Play` at 8KHz, so it just gets floating-point aliasing noise when it's told to sample an 8KHz note (which it then gleefully amplifies to an audible level, resulting in something which is remarkably stupid-sounding).

Comment: Please delete your incorrect comment and off-topic answer. Regards.

Comment: I clarified the comment I left under your question. "nshaffer" already posted the complete answer, so I posted this answer for supplementary amusement purposes.

Comment: Also, it does answer the question, just indirectly.

Comment: Wish I could test this "stupid-sounding" sample, but alas no Mathematica & WolframAlpha doesn't understand 'play.' Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

This should sound like a sine wave.

However if your cycle is too long, it is not audible to the human ear. To be audible, the cycle should be over 20Hz, or 20 times a second.